# Removing duplicates within a cell

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I can't find a way to remove duplicate values inside a same cell in Excel. For example, in A1, I have:

```
DOG DOG DOG
```

I want to have only `DOG`.

Code output: This will result certain values in the Excel cell (37, 4), such as:

```
2000 3000 0300 0300 2000
```

I am lost as to how to delete the repeated values in the cell.

Comment: Is it always one word repeated, or will there be other words, like "Dog Cat Dog" with the desired output "Dog Cat"?

Comment: Hi Scott. It will be like "Dog Cat Dog Cat". I would be looking for output to be "Dog Cat"

Comment: I am using VBScript. sorry for the confusion

Comment: could you post an example of what you have tried?

Comment: I have added what I have tried, but I am lost as to how to handle value duplications inside a same cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex with a backreference to match duplicated words or phrases. The nongreedy pattern `^(.+?)\s(\1\s*)+$` will match any duplicating phrase with whitespace in between.

```
Function RemoveDupes(strText)
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "^(.+?)\s(\1\s*)+$"
        If .Test(strText) Then RemoveDupes = .Replace(strText, "$1")
    End With
End Function
```

Tests:

```
WScript.Echo RemoveDupes("Dog Cat Dog Cat")         ' => Dog Cat
WScript.Echo RemoveDupes("Dog Dog")                 ' => Dog
WScript.Echo RemoveDupes("Dog Dog Dog")             ' => Dog
WScript.Echo RemoveDupes("Dog Dog Dog Dog")         ' => Dog
WScript.Echo RemoveDupes("Dog Cat Dog Cat Dog Cat") ' => Dog Cat
```

**Edit**:

I see you've added some additional examples that don't repeat perfectly as your original examples did. In that case, you'll need to use an alternative method. If your values are always separated by a space, consider splitting your values into an array and storing them into a Dictionary to keep track of unique values. For example:

```
Dim d, a, i
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
a = Split(objExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), " ")

For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    If Not d.Exists(a(i)) Then d.Add a(i), ""
Next
```

Now your Dictionary should have unique values from your cell and you can recombine them:

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = Join(d.Keys, " ")
```

Comment: Can you please provide a bit of detail on your edit? I have never used scripting dictionary

Comment: It's just an associative array (key/value pairs). Each key needs to be unique. [`Dictionary.Add(key, value)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h92h863(v=vs.84).aspx) is the method to add new entries. So you can add each "word" of your cell as a key in the dictionary to filter unique values.

Comment: I got it working, there was an error in another looping, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like...  We need to know where the space is between DOG DOG..

Excel:

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)
```

VBS:

```
Left(string, length)
```

Ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3xcs8k%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

InStr:

```
SOMESTRING = "DOG DOG DOG"
InStr (1, SOMESTRING, " ") '-- look for the position of the space
```

Ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Putting the two together we get:

```
SOMESTRING = "DOG DOG DOG"
RESULTS = Left(SOMESTRING, InStr (1, SOMESTRING, " ")-1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You've answered the specific example rather than an approach that works for any text.